# Functions vs using If else

Tags: php, forms, function, if-statement

I'm currently learning PHP and need some advice.

I have a file called process.php that will do processing data from the submitted form, from insert and update page.

Currently my process is more or less like this:

```
$action = $_POST['action'] //insert or update
if($action=='insert'){
  //do insert action
} else if($action=='update') {
  //do update action
}
```

So, I'm wondering, if creating and calling a function will be better than using if-else-if. Or you can tell me a better way than the 2 above, any advice is appreciated :).

Thank you for your time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you plan to use the code in 1 place only, do not create a function.
My suggestion is to use a switch statement:

```
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '';

switch ($action) {
  case 'insert':
    //do insert action
    break;
  case 'update':
    //do update action
    break;
  default:
    //action is empty
}
```

Comment: Wow so fast... I'm sorry if my question is too noob-ish.
I see, i never considered using Switch. Thank you sir, i learn something new.

Comment: @ShiraIshikawa The question is ok. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

> A key benefit of using functions is that they are reusable; if you have a task that needs to be performed a number of times, a function is an ideal solution.

[See more](http://www.sitepoint.com/defining-and-using-functions-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Dmitri Pavlutin - if code located only there you don't need to create a function.

In my opinion, If-else statements are easier than Switch

Comment: yeah, i consider function since if i using if-else then it have to check condition 1 by 1, and i want to avoid that by calling an insert or update function instead if-else. Well, i'm using switch now, since it seems better.